# Problem while executing hadoop code

Tags: java, hadoop

I just started with Hadoop. I wrote a sample hadoop code as was written in the book. But still, during the time of execution exceptions arise. The snippet of what I get :

[harsh@geek hadoop-0.20.2]$ hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MaxTemperature
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MaxTemperature
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: MaxTemperature.  Program will exit.

What shall I do?

Comment: did you compile your code with a compiler (`javac`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a hadoop jar this is the command which you should run in the directory you put the jar in (e.g. /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin )

- hadoop jar NAMEOFJAR.jar arg1 arg2 argN

from your question this could be how to run it (make the cd to hadoop directory for the version of hadoop your running)

- cp MaxTemperature.jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin
- su hadoop
- cd /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin
- hadoop jar MaxTemperature.jar input/ncdc/sample.txt output

Comment: does that mean that I have to create a jar file for my code? the book also said this but it was written in the way as if it were just an option. and if I have to, how do I make one?

Comment: you do have to make a jar file.  if you're using eclipse, there's an option for it.  a tutorial shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Add the MaxTemperature class to your class path.

Comment: I tried it. It still didn't work. "set CLASSPATH=/home/harsh/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/MaxTemp.java 
"

Comment: or probably you asked me to do something else? because I am totally new to Hadoop as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I was under the impression it would work much the same as the java classpath issues that resemble this problem, based on your tags.

Comment: my bad! the book also says about setting classpath. "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=build/classes" I did even this but still I get the same error.

Comment: I am doing this through command line and i have been stuck for almost a day now with this.

Answer (score 0):

It always looks for the entry point which is the main class, the piece of code which sets your mapper and reducer class. If it cant find it, it throws classnotfound exception.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. I documented a step by step solution on http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=256. Hope it helps someone

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put MaxTemperature in a package?

If so, say your `MaxTemperature.class` file is in `yourdir/bin/yourpackage/`. You need to do:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=yourdir/bin
hadoop yourpackage.MaxTemperature
```

Answer (score 0):

For Map Reduce Execution first you need to create Jar file with the classes i.e. Mapper,Reducer,Driver class.
Move to folder where jar file is located and execute

```
bin/hadoop Sample.jar SampleDriver InputFileName OutPutFileName
```

Try it. should Work with these flow.